# Leave a rigged figure in its design after rendering

Tags: rigging

I designed a Rigged figure in a certain position and when I render it returns to the upright position with arms outstretched to the sides.
How do you fix the character in the desired position that will not change during rendering?

Comment: Have you tried inserting a keyframe with the 'I' key with everything selected before rendering?

Comment: Or have you deleted all keyframes on the rig which seem to be already there which is why it gets reset upon rendering?

Comment: It's rendered this way, but can't it be converted to mesh, so I can move it from place to place as a stable sculpt? I want to make pictures, not animation.

Comment: Or have you deleted all keyframes on the rig which seem to be already there which is why it gets reset upon rendering? – 
Gordon Brinkmann
--Oh, that's better, thank you very much!